# Kivy ToggleButtonBehavior

Tags: python, kivy

I try to build a toggle between two or more labels like radio buttons. It work so far with the ToggleButtonBehavior to change the state between the group but when I click the selected item it get deselected and should not do it.

```
class SelectButton(ToggleButtonBehavior, Label):
    active = BooleanProperty(False)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SelectButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.text='off'
        self.color=[1,0,1,1]

        self.bind(state=self.toggle)

    def toggle(self, instance, value):
        if self.state == 'down':
            self.text = 'on'
        else:
            self.text = 'off'
```

Is there a way to get a behavior like a radio button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`allow_no_selection` property](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.html#kivy.uix.behaviors.ToggleButtonBehavior.allow_no_selection):

> This specifies whether the widgets in a group allow no selection i.e.
>   everything to be deselected.
>
> allow_no_selection is a BooleanProperty and defaults to True

After setting it to `False` and using a group everything starts to work as intended:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ToggleButtonBehavior
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<MyWidget>:
    SelectButton:
        state: 'down'
        text: 'on'
    SelectButton
        state: 'normal'
        text: 'off'
    SelectButton
        state: 'normal'
        text: 'off'
''')

class SelectButton(ToggleButtonBehavior, Label):
    active = BooleanProperty(False)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SelectButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.allow_no_selection = False

        self.group = "mygroup"
        self.color=[1,0,1,1]

        self.bind(state=self.toggle)

    def toggle(self, instance, value):
        if self.state == 'down':
            self.text = 'on'
        else:
            self.text = 'off'

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```